# CSS Responsive Design - display : table-cell with display : none inbetween breaking Chrome based browsers

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari

I was trying to make a responsive website to display some product details for a store. I want it to display 1 product per row at the small window width, 2 products per row at a medium window width and 3 products per row at a large window width with the number of products on the page being a multiple of 6.

I thought I could make each product div display : table-cell and have a div after 2n products (class fizz) and after 3n products (class buzz) and alternate between using display : none; and display : table-row; on the different classes to get it to display the correct number of products per row.

It seems to work in Internet Explorer 11, Opera 12.17 and Firefox 28, but Chrome 34, Safari 5.17, and Opera 20 don't respond to the CSS as I want at the media queries. If I resize the window so it activates the CSS it stuffs up the layout, but if I refresh the page at the new window size it displays the content correctly.

```
Code in JSFiddle
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YhEu4/2/)

Any suggestions to what is causing it not to work properly

I was trying to get it to work with only CSS, no Javascript or JQuery.

Comment: Ah i feel terrible, have been trying to solve this from a while now... let me know if you find any solution...!!

Comment: Yeah the stupid thing works on browser refresh in chrome, safari and opera 20 at the different window sizes, so while the code might be horrible it does work. But the firing of the media queries it is like it doesn't change .fizz or .buzz from display : table-row to display : none before trying to change the .products width.